# Scrapy Inspect_Response in second-level crawls: MultipleInstanceError errors for iPython

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, ipython

I'm getting acquainted with Scrapy and heavily relying on the interactive debugger, `inspect_response()`.

I'm starting by scraping events off a calendar. Step 1 is to get the overview, step 2 is to get the details:

```
|-- Calendar List Page
|   `-- Calendar Event Details Page
```

Here is my implementation:

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "my first spider"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://www.ticketfly.com/venue/7337-output/']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_overview)

    def parse_overview(self, response):
        for event in response.css('.list-view-item'):
            # This works fine: inspect_response(response, self)
            details = event.css('span.ticket-link.primary-link a::attr(href)').extract_first()

            if details is not None:
              yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(details),
                                   callback=self.parse_url)

    def parse_url(self, response):
        inspect_response(response, self) # This breaks
```

`inspect_response()` works fine on in step 1, but fails in step 2:

```
2017-04-22 10:30:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.ticketfly.com/purchase/event/1465896/tfly> (referer: https://www.ticketfly.com/venue/7337-output/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/me/test/scrapy/test/test/spiders/my_spider.py", line 37, in parse_url
    inspect_response(response, self)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 167, in inspect_response
    Shell(spider.crawler).start(response=response)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 81, in start
    banner=self.vars.pop('banner', ''))
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/console.py", line 82, in start_python_console
    shell(namespace=namespace, banner=banner)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/console.py", line 22, in wrapper
    banner1=banner, user_ns=namespace, config=config)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 416, in instance
    '%s are being created.' % cls.__name__
MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances of InteractiveShellEmbed are being created.
2017-04-22 10:30:47 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger
2017-04-22 10:30:47 [root] DEBUG: Using default logger
2017-04-22 10:30:47 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.ticketfly.com/purchase/event/1457966/tfly> (referer: https://www.ticketfly.com/venue/7337-output/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/me/test/scrapy/test/test/spiders/my_spider.py", line 37, in parse_url
    inspect_response(response, self)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 167, in inspect_response
    Shell(spider.crawler).start(response=response)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/shell.py", line 81, in start
    banner=self.vars.pop('banner', ''))
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/console.py", line 82, in start_python_console
    shell(namespace=namespace, banner=banner)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/console.py", line 22, in wrapper
    banner1=banner, user_ns=namespace, config=config)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 416, in instance
    '%s are being created.' % cls.__name__
MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances of InteractiveShellEmbed are being created.
```

Comment: Well your spider is working fine. How are you running it? It seems like the shell doesn't open up and doesn't block the spider so it keeps trying to open up new shells. Could be an issue with windows or anaconda too. Does it work without ipython?

Comment: Good question. It works if I set the shell to python or bpython in scrapy.cfg

Comment: Seems like the issue lies with `ipython`, have you tried reinstalling it or starting up a new virtual environment?

Comment: No, I'm loathe to reinstall it since it's part of Anaconda... I'm afraid it'll mess up all my other packages. I guess I have to take the plunge...

Comment: I'm running plain scrapy and I have also ran into this issue and logged an issue here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10632 I'm on python 3.6 with ipython 6.1.0 on osx